# Locust, how to access custom command line argument from LoadTestShape

Tags: python, listener, locust

I create a listener for new command line argument:

```
@events.init_command_line_parser.add_listener
def init_parser(parser):
    parser.add_argument("--stages", type=str, env_var="LOCUST_STAGES", help="It's working")
```

but I don't have a clue how to get access to this value.
Trying something like:

```
@events.init.add_listener
def _(environment, **kw):
    os.environ['stages'] = environment.parsed_options.stages
```

But there is no effect, because command : `os.environ.get('stages')` returns None

How should I get this value? Especially if I only use it with others like:

```
locust -f locustfiles/file.py --tag some_tag --stages stages.json
```

Comment: `environment.parsed_options.stages` is the value. Why are you trying to add it to the `environment` dictionary?

Comment: For now I see only that way to pass value inside my Class(inherited from LoadTestShape). Mb I am wrong, dunno, but it is a quick solution that must work and I can check

Answer (score 2):

You can access the locust environment inside your LoadTestShape class using `self.runner.environment` (same as in a User/@task)

So you can do something like

```
def tick(self):
    print(self.runner.environment.parsed_options.stages)
    ...
```

(note: you need 1.4.4 for this to work)

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work, because LoadTestShape class doesn't have attribute - runner:
`AttributeError: 'StagesShape' object has no attribute 'runner`

Comment: The same situation when I tried `self.environment.parsed_options.stages` which is available under @task (FastHttpUser)

Comment: I just found out that this behaviour was only in master, not yet released.

Comment: It happens :). Thanks anyway, I will track. For now will use os

Comment: It is released now in 1.4.4

Answer (score 1):

to add custom arguments, via CLI check [github](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/add_command_line_argument.py):

```
    @events.init_command_line_parser.add_listener
def init_parser(parser):
    parser.add_argument("--customarg", type=str, env_var="LOCUST_MY_ARGUMENT", default="1234", help="It's working")

@events.init.add_listener
def _(environment, **kw):
    print("Custom argument supplied: %s" % environment.parsed_options.customarg)
```

to get it inside your class User **init**, use:

```
print(self.environment.parsed_options.customarg)
```

and run like:

```
locust -f locustfile.py --customarg CUSTOM_VALUE --headless -u 10 -r 10 --run-time 5s
```

Comment: Thanks, but I saw this example and it didn't help. All problem was in LoadTestShape classes, there is no environment field(attribute) in that class, at least in previous versions

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to your custom argument value by the next way.
First - create parser variable:

```
import argparse
locust_parser_settings = argparse.ArgumentParser(
  prog='locust',
  usage='==SUPPRESS==',
  description='\nUsage: locust [OPTIONS] [UserClass ...]\n\n',
  formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
  conflict_handler='error',
  add_help=True
)
```

Then write your hook function with returning of argument value:

```
@events.init_command_line_parser.add_listener
    def locust_add_option_and_get_option_value(parser):
      parser.add_argument("--my-argument", type=str, env_var="LOCUST_MY_ARGUMENT", default="", help="It's working")
      my_argument = parser.parse_known_args()[0].my_argument
      return my_argument
```

And at the end you should forcibly call your hook:

```
my_custom_arg = locust_add_option_and_get_option_value(parser=locust_parser_settings)
```